# nullColumnHack not working

Tags: android, sqlite, null

I'm creating a table *before* adding information to it because I need its ID. Code:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
Long id = db.insert(PersonEntry.TABLE_NAME, PersonEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NULLABLE, values);
```

However, I get this error:

```
near "NULL": syntax error
Error inserting
near "NULL": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO person(NULL) VALUES (NULL)
```

The code works if I put some fake values in *values*, but that shouldn't be necessary given the nullColumnHack. What am I missing?

Schema:

```
public static abstract class PersonEntry implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_NULLABLE = "NULL";
    ...
}
```

Creation of table:

```
private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
        "CREATE TABLE " + PersonEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                PersonEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NULLABLE + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                ...
                " )";

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
}
```

Comment: `nullColumnHack` is supposed to be one of your 'normal' columns.

Answer (score 2):

Use a name other than `NULL` for your null column, it's a reserved word. Something like `NULLHACK` might be better. Alternatively, name one of your other columns as the null column hack.